# Swift textfield - decide whether the view have to pushed up or not

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with handling the keyboard correctly.

**The entire view is filled with text fields.**

When I'm working with the notifications to move the view up the upper textboxes are no longer visible:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 150
}
```

Has one of you an idea how to distinguish which textfield is selected (behind the upcoming keyboard or above the keyboard) to decide whether the view have to pushed up or not?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not move your parent view up and down. The best way to do this instead of using Notifications is, by placing all your text fields within a scrollview . Later in your view controller class you can use Text Field delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Within this method set the scrollview contentOffset property like this

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textField.center.y-80); // you can change 80 to whatever which fits your needs
```

Later when Text Field resigns first responder, when tapping outside of text fields  then you need to set back the offset value of scrollview. you can use this Text Field delegate method to set back scroll view offset

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,-80);
}
```

Note: you need to make every text field in your view to have their delegate as your UIViewController instance. You also need need your UiViewController to adopt UITextFieldDelegate

Answer (score 3):

You most likely want your text fields in a scroll view, then you should change the view frame height, not the origin. Once you change the frame you can scroll the view content to ensure that the part you want is visible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, that I'm aware of, to know which **UITextField** was selected using notifications.

For this I suggest assigning each **UITextField** a unique **tag** value and assign the **delegate** property for each to the same **UIViewController** instance.

Have the view controller adopt the **UITextFieldDelegate** protocol and implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)`

All [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) methods receive the **UITextField** object that you can then read the **tag** property value to determine which textfield became first responder and make decisions from there.